# Delphi Dinamic controls

Tags: delphi

Как реализовать функцию очистки динамически созданного Image?
Создаю Image в цикле. Имя у него:

```
ArrOfImage[i].Name :='ImgP'+IntToStr[i];
.... ( куча остальных свойств)
ArrOfImage[i].Paren := TabSheepArrP[i]; // ну тут соответственно размещение на TabSheep который тоже создается программно. ( Все создается в 1 цикле =>  друг другу соответствует.
```

Нужно очистить все `Image` с подобным именем.

Делаю так:

```
for fmMain.PageControl2.ControlCount-1 downto 0 do // Все это создается как вы поняли на 2-ом PageControl
begin
  if Pos('ImgP',fmMain.PageControl2.Controls[i].Name) <> 0 then
     TImage(fmMain.PageControl2.Controls[i]).Picture := nil;
end;
```

Вроде бы все логично, и должно работать, но почему-то `fmMain.PageControl2.ControlCount = 1` 
и `Name` у данного контрола - это имя `TabSheet`, и как я понимаю он не видит `Image`.

Подскажите как решить данную проблему?

P.S.: Если чем-то поможет: пытаюсь получить ссылку на `Image` при помощи `FindComponent`, функция возвращает `nil`.

Comment: `Dinamic`, `Paren`, поправьте опечатки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так размещать надо не только заданием парента, но ещё сделать AddControl (или что то подобное не помню уже), автоматом оно не добавляется в список контролов парента.

Answer (score 0):

Создаете на табшит, а ищите на пейджконтрол.

выглядеть будет примерно так

```
var i,z:integer; 
begin 
i:=pc.Pages[0].ControlCount; 
for z := 0 to i-1 do  
 begin   
showmessage( pc.Pages[0].Controls[z].Name) ;
  end;
```

end;

PC= PageControl

вместо Showmessage уже делаете свое условие.